# How to use cloud function auth trigger flutter/dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How can I create a new document when the user registered with email and password, I want to use auth trigger to add data like

```
Collection('user').document(uid).field('email':email@gmail.com)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use the cloud function for this. In my opinion, this addition can be done manually by typing it directly into the database

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the official documentation for the Authentication triggers [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events), basically you have to create a cloud function that will listen to the "functions.auth.user().onCreate()" event handler as explained in the documentation.

```
exports.registerUserData = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {

  const email = user.email;
  const uid = user.uid
  //save the record as you want, you can access to more properties of "UserRecord"

});
```

If you want to know more about what "UserRecord" contains on this event, you can take a look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord.html)